# What patch is played at worlds of Season 4?

Tags: league-of-legends

In the notes of [4.14](http://euw.leagueoflegends.com/en/news/game-updates/patch/patch-414-notes) they said:

> As 4.14 is **potentially** the patch we'll be playing the World Championship on

Which on is it finally? 4.14 got updated once more after the realease.

Answer (score 4):

The LoL 2014 World Championship is played on [Patch 4.14](http://na.lolesports.com/articles/414-world-championship-patch) just as they initially announced in the patch notes you mentioned above.